# Troubleshooting Anacron

Tags: rsync

I'm running into a few problems in using Anacron. The code I'm using was adapted from a website in the Linux Gazette and I've already had to make a couple of changes for my code to even work, but the tar commands aren't running and the other jobs (I did a force) are failing because there's nothing to get them started.

I'm also running into an issue where anacron doesn't seem to be starting with my computer (by checking `ps -e|grep anacron`). As for that, unless I put anacron in the forefront, it doesn't seem to be giving me any options at all.

I'm aware that the rsync code is off, but it's not my biggest concern right now.

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin


# Rsync over SSH the tarballed files below
1   5   backup  rsync -auz -e "ssh -i ~/.sshkeys/diskstation-rsync-key" /backups/* asturm@sturmundrang.diskstation.me


# Back up user-generated Linux files with snapshots of 6,4,3,2,1 months and 3,2,1 weeks - /home /etc    /var
# Order 4m->6m, 3m->4m, 2m->3m, 1m->2m, 3w->1m, 2w->3w, 1w->2w, mirror->1w

# Every 60 days (2 months)
60  20  home    cp -f /backups/home/4month.tar.gz /backups/home/6month.tar.gz
60  20  etc cp -f /backups/etc/4month.tar.gz /backups/etc/6month.tar.gz
60 20 var cp -f /backups/var/4month.tar.gz /backups/var/6month.tar.gz

# every 30 days (1 month)
30 22 home4 cp -f /backups/home/3month.tar.gz /backups/home/4month.tar.gz
30 24 home5 cp -f /backups/home/2month.tar.gz /backups/home/3month.tar.gz
30 26 home6 cp -f /backups/home/1month.tar.gz /backups/home/2month.tar.gz
30 28 home7 cp -f /backups/home/3week.tar.gz  /backups/home/1month.tar.gz

# every 30 days (1 month)
30 22 etc4 cp -f /backups/etc/3month.tar.gz /backups/etc/4month.tar.gz
30 24 etc5 cp -f /backups/etc/2month.tar.gz /backups/etc/3month.tar.gz
30 26 etc6 cp -f /backups/etc/1month.tar.gz /backups/etc/2month.tar.gz
30 28 etc7 cp -f /backups/etc/3week.tar.gz  /backups/etc/1month.tar.gz

# every 30 days (1 month)
30 22 var4 cp -f /backups/var/3month.tar.gz /backups/var/4month.tar.gz
30 24 var5 cp -f /backups/var/2month.tar.gz /backups/var/3month.tar.gz
30 26 var6 cp -f /backups/var/1month.tar.gz /backups/var/2month.tar.gz
30 28 var7 cp -f /backups/var/3week.tar.gz  /backups/var/1month.tar.gz

# And every 7 days - pass everything up and remove the week 1 backup.
7 30 home1 cp -f /backups/home/2week.tar.gz  /backups/home/3week.tar.gz
7 32 home2 cp -f /backups/home/1week.tar.gz  /backups/home/2week.tar.gz 
7 34 home3 rm -f /backups/home/1week.tar.gz

7 30 etc1 cp -f /backups/etc/2week.tar.gz  /backups/etc/3week.tar.gz
7 32 etc2 cp -f /backups/etc/1week.tar.gz  /backups/etc/2week.tar.gz 
7 34 etc3 rm -f /backups/etc/1week.tar.gz

7 30 var1 cp -f /backups/var/2week.tar.gz  /backups/var/3week.tar.gz
7 32 var2 cp -f /backups/var/1week.tar.gz  /backups/var/2week.tar.gz 
7 34 var3 rm -f /backups/var/1week.tar.gz


# Tarball these folders every week
7   36  hometar tar -zcf /backups/home/1week.tar.gz /home/*
7   36  etctar  tar -zcf /backups/etc/1week.tar.gz /etc/*
7   36  vartar  tar -zcf /backups/var/1week.tar.gz /var/*

# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily   nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly  nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: Did you do anything special to make `anacron` launch at startup?  Check if there is a script to start it anywhere in `/etc/init.d/`.  If so, and if that script is *not* linked from `/etc/rc#.d/` (where `#` is your runlevel of choice, probably `2`), then you should add a link for it (something like `S99anacron`).

Comment: I think the issue above all was that I had no idea how to get to the /var/log/syslog that Timothy was talking about in his answer.

When I looked into the file, I saw that anacron was running and it was processing the backups, so that should work. As I've said, I've tested the codes and I now know anacron is automated.

As a backup, I've set up a crontab and rsync and the log helped me find out why that wasn't working too.

But yes: I did set up the folders beforehand.

Comment: For debugging run `sudo anacron -fnd`. Helped me alot to fix my anacrontab. It will force execution, ignore timestamps, ignore delays, dont go to background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created the requisite directories?  `tar` will not create non-existent directories.
If not, this will do the trick.

`mkdir -p /backups/home`

The `tar` command will fail if any directories do not exist where you are attempting to create your `tar.gz` file, making it seem that `anacron` is not working.

Checking the contents of `/var/log/cron` (Redhat-based location) or `/var/log/syslog` (Debian-based), should show that `anacron` indeed runs your jobs.  If there is an `exit status` shown along with `mailing output` next to the `Job terminated` message, `anacron` ran but the job(s) failed.

Comment: That pretty much summed it up.